# Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.00

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, google-cast

I'm using Android Studio and have cloned the [CastVideo v2 reference app](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android-v2) and set it up with the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android) as per its instructions.

However, when I try to sync the gradle project, it says: `Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.00`.
I have the option to `Install Repository and sync project` but it does nothing.

I have tried doing `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`, removing and reinstalling `Google Repository` and `Google Play services` with the SDK Manager, changing dependency version and renaming to `play-services-cast-framework`, with no success.

My `build.gradle`s are unchanged from those in the repos.

Does anyone know how to fix this? SO and Google searches have been unfruitful, as has reading other unresolved dependency questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Currently** the dependency doesn't exist:

Use

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.6.1
```

instead of

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.00
```

**EDIT:**

**Today (25/10/2016) is available in SDK Manager.**
Just update the SDK Manager and use:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.0
```

Official link: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Makes no sense, according to this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#october_2016_-_v98

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Now it is available in SDK Manager: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.

Comment: Thank you, this morning's update to Google Repository has added v9.8.0. The cast reference app developers must have had access to a more bleeding edge update channel.

Answer (score 11):

i facing the same problem, here is what i do :

- open your app build.gradle
- change `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.00` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:9.8.0`

i notice it after updating my google repository.

hope this helps

Comment: @Marco7757 glad it helps :)